# how is google able to provide free calls to US/CANADA from gmail?

Tags: gmail, call

Could anyone help me understand how the server/PBX mechanics would work for Google free calls trough gmail. Do they host hundreds of phone lines across the country and link them with VoIP. To they have a central location and preferred pricing from the telecoms. Basically, I would like to replicate part of this functionality for a web app im creating. How can they offer free calls to landlines?

Comment: This is more of a pricing question than a programming question...

Comment: I think your question belongs to http://serverfault.com/